# mongoDB compass doesn't work! how to make it work .error mongodb-compass

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-20.10

mongoDB compass doesn't work!
installed  [on this site](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/install/)
before that there was also a problem, I had to reinstall ubuntu [in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1328627/%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-inrelease-source)

```
[23114:0923/070140.222706:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(894)] The display compositor is frequently crashing. Goodbye.
```

Additional Information

```
sudo systemctl status mongod
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor>
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-09-23 06:44:41 EEST; 18s ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
   Main PID: 18125 (mongod)
     Memory: 60.7M
        CPU: 685ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/mongod.service
             └─18125 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf

sep 23 06:44:41 d991 systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: help me please!!

Comment: Facing the same problem. Ubuntu 21.10. Latest compass. Same error.

Comment: With a much lighter and functional alternative https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mongodb.mongodb-vscode I don't miss the Compass. You could try and use it until someone figures out a fix. @dengood